# ASP.NET: Internal Site Search

Tags: asp.net, search, full-text-search

I'm searching for some internal site search code.

The scenario is:

**I'm having a site in which the content comes from database (CMS) which makes the pages dynamic. So the search tool should search this dynamic content too.**

I don't want to use readymade search engines like google, bing etc....

Do I need to make my own search control for this or would I get a ready code? If I would have to make my own then what approach should I take?

Answer (score 2):

[Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) can search files and database, or any text-based content. See [here](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx) how to start. You can also buy a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394281). For documentation, you can search for Java examples, wikis and docs, because it's direct port so most of concepts for on .NET version also.

Comment: Yea, Lucene.NET is a great API too, you can use LINQ to Lucine too(http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use google search to search in your pages, see 
[How can I add a Google search box to my Web site?](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html)

Comment: Well...I don't want google or any other search engines...and want to build inbuilt site search functionality...